# Webpack fonts semantic-ui

Tags: webpack, semantic-ui

I can't get semantic-ui fonts to work with webpack, I still end up with a 404 not found error.

Apparently, the output path of fonts go to the root of my web server 
`http://localhost/build/fonts/icons.woff2`

I need it to be at 
`http://localhost/my_projet/build/fonts/icons.woff2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution may work, but with webpack encore you can do this:

```
Encore.setPublicPath('your_project/path_of_your_build')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote this seems to be something you can configure with webpack. I'm aware of two possible ways to do this, however it depends on your configuration which one will be good for you, or if the combination of both will solve your problem.

**A)** configuring the module.loaders [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)'s (or url-loader's, which is based on file-loader) `name` parameter to use the full path:

```
{
     test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
     loader: 'url-loader?name=/full/path/to/fonts/[name].[ext]'
}
```

**B)** using [output.publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath)

```
output: {
    filename: myProjectBundleFileName,
    publicPath: '/full/path/on/host'
},
```

If you use the public path, do not include the full path for the font loader:

```
{
     test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
     loader: 'url-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
}
```